# What´s the specific function to fully change a players name?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I´ve been looking around the Internet for a week trying to discover a useable function that I can use to change a players name in my Plugin, and since most information is waaaaay to old, I was unsuccessful to find anything.
This is what I have tried already:

```
 player.setCustomName(args[0]);
 player.setDisplayName(args[0]);
 player.setPlayerListName(args[0]);
 getConfig().set(player.getName(),args[0]);
```

Its not like I receive a Error or something, its just that not much happens to the player names (but the function is actually called, I checked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you cannot change your full name that you entered in the client settings.

These methods you are trying to use will only change the name of the in-game server for the player object. These also affect the names of the chat, tablist and possibly scoreboard teams. There is a solution that can be used to change the player name for a given player in half, but it will not affect other servers or the client either. Using `GameProfile` from *Mojang*, you can change its name and UUID, but this requires creating a new instance and adding it to the existing `PlayerInfoData` list. If you don't have *Spigot/Paper* or some software attached to your project, you'll need to use Java Reflections to modify the values/list and everything else, especially in `PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo`. Or, if you want to avoid Java Reflections, you can use the `PlayerProfile` interface implemented by *Paper*, using the `Player#getPlayerProfile` method.

An example code using Reflections:

```java
Player player = ...; // Your player object here
GameProfile gameProfile = new GameProfile(player.getUniqueId(), "newPlayerNameHere");

// packet is the new instance of PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo
// infoList is the list retrieved from PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo
// playerInfoDataConstr is the PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo constructor
// ping is the amount of ping the player have currently
// gameMode is the EnumGameMode object of the player
// text is the text parsed to IChatBaseComponent

((List<Object>) infoList.get(packet)).add(playerInfoDataConstr.newInstance(packet, gameProfile, ping, gameMode, getAsIChatBaseComponent(text)));

// Send the packet object to every online player on the server
```

For accessing to GameProfile class you'll need `com.mojang.authlib` dependency.

*Using Paper API is kinda easy to implement.*

Comment: ty so much for this detailed answer

Comment: i do believe we have Spigot/Paper, yet trying to change the name via player.getPlayerProfile().setName([name]) has no result, do i need to change my approach?(could this be due to me not checking if we accually have the mojang.authlib dependency?)

Comment: Just setting the profile name is not enough. You have to cache the `player.getPlayerProfile`, set the name, after that set the new player profile.

`PlayerProfile profile = player.getPlayerProfile(); profile.setName(name); player.setPlayerProfile(profile);`
Edit: `GameProfile` is not the same with `PlayerProfile` this class is provided by Paper, GameProfile is from Mojang.